# posting images into users feed with source is not working

Tags: facebook

i am trying to create a fb app using the user profile pic. app will generate a new image that image should post to user feed. I am trying to use "source" but it is not working. This is not giving full image. It gives thumbnails instead of posting full image. Here is my code

```
     $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width,$crop_height);

     imagecopy($canvas,$currentimage,0,0,0,0,$crop_width,$crop_height);

     $test = $data['user_id'].'test.jpg';

     imagejpeg($canvas, $test,100);

     $new = imagecreatetruecolor(150,150);

     imagecopyresized($new,$canvas,0,0,0,0,150,150,$w,$crop_height);

     $resize1 = $data['user_id'].'resize1.jpg';

     imagejpeg($new, $resize1 ,100);

     $source1 = 'black.jpg';

     $background = imagecreatefromjpeg($source1);

     $resize = imagecreatefromjpeg($resize1);

     imagecopy($background,$resize,100,250,0,0,150,150);

     $output = $data['user_id'].'output.jpg';

     imagejpeg($background,$output,100);

     echo '<div align="center"><img src="'.$output.'"></div>';  
     unlink($test);

     unlink($resize1);

     $access_token = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
     $graph_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=".$access_token."&method=post&source=http://www.Google.es/images/srpr/nav_logo39.png&message=logo";
     $user_permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
      print_r($user_permissions);
```

Please help me this solves me to create a perfect fb app.